# how to select columns by index in a datatable vbnet

Tags: indexing, multiple-columns

Someone knows how to select (ex) columns from 3 to 12 of a datatable?
In matlab for example exists some ':' operator to indicate "take all elements", i need some sort of that in vbnet

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is your question how to implement this matlab statement in VB.Net?

```
datatable(:, 3:12)
```

So you want to get column 3 to 12 from every row right?

I don't recognize any method other than iteration. Here is a little example which should create the desired output for datatable(:,1:3). Note that startVal in this case is 1 and endVal is 3:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        ' Create a table.
        Dim table As DataTable = New DataTable("Example")

        ' Add columns.
        table.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("ID", GetType(Integer)))
        table.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Name", GetType(String)))
        table.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Letters", GetType(Integer)))
        table.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Animal", GetType(String)))

        ' Add rows.
        table.Rows.Add(10, "Hello", 5, "Dog")
        table.Rows.Add(20, "World", 5, "Cat")
        table.Rows.Add(30, "Example", 7, "Mouse")
        table.Rows.Add(40, "For", 3, "Horse")
        table.Rows.Add(50, "You", 3, "Elephant")

        ' Define your start and end.
        Dim startVal As Integer = 1
        Dim endVal As Integer = 3

        ' Iterate the Rows.
        For indexRows = 0 To table.Rows.Count - 1
            ' Get current Row.
            Dim currentRow As DataRow = table.Rows.Item(indexRows)
            ' Iterate your desired Columns.
            For indexColumns = startVal To endVal
                ' Write the current Column and add some Whitespace for better readability.
                Console.Write(currentRow(indexColumns) & vbTab)
            Next
            ' When done with the CurrentRow add a Linebreak for the next Row
            Console.WriteLine()
        Next
    End Sub

End Module
```